# itunes: delete song from playlist

Tags: itunes, playlists

I can't seem to remove a particular song from one of my playlists, but keep it in my collection. Pressing "delete" or "command+delete" doesn't seem to do anything. Option+delete asks me if I want to remove it from my music library, which is not what I want.

help!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem:

I wasn't viewing a playlist, I was viewing a playlist folder, and it was showing me all the songs from each of the playlists in the folder simultaneously. When I clicked on the particular playlist, it let me remove the song from that playlist.

Makes sense! (I just wish they had put up a dialog box saying "cannot remove songs when viewing more than one playlist")